# Import statement when developing with Flask (JS and Python)

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I am having troubles to identify why I can't import CSS-in-JS easily in a simple React-Flask project. For sake of simplicity, I am not using either Webpack, Babel or NPM (I want to understand React in a simple way first). The structure of the files is the following:

```
+-- main.py (to start Flask)
+-- templates
    +-- index.html (default html to load at "/")
+-- static
    +-- App.js (Dummy simple React.Component inside)
```

In short, I am using a CDN to include `styled-components` in `index.html` as:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/3.3.2/styled-components.min.js"></script>`

Reactjs and jQuery are also included this way. Then I include the dummy component as:

`<script src = {{url_for('static', filename = 'App.js')}} type = "module"></script>`

Up to here, everything works fine (that is, a default component loads and works). The problem comes when I try to use `styled-components`: in this `App.js` file, if I write `import styled from 'styled-components'` the webpage does not load, and there is no error output in the console to help me figure out what is wrong. It is not an ES6 issue because I am using Edge 16 and Firefox Quantum 60, and the import/export statements work perfectly with self-defined components. It troubles me that there is no error output at the console. I am fairly new to JS, so I didn't know how to exactly search for this issue, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up using `styled-components`, and I went for another CSS-in-JS library, `Radium`. It seems like (correct me if I am wrong) the import statements only work for local files (so I would need a local copy of the `Radium.js` lib to make it work), so the CDN already "includes" some things (for example, using the CDN for `React.js` already gives the `React` "variable" across all java scripts defined, the same goes for `PropTypes` using the CDN for `prop-types`. I can easily use the `Radium` "variable" as long as I included the Radium CDN, however, it was just impossible to use the `styled` variable even after including the `styled-components` CDN. I guess this counts as a solution!